# fscanf reading everything except for first line

Tags: c

```
int k;
float regionID;
int t;
char string[100];
float avgTemp,totalTemp;
for(k = 0; k < MAX_STATIONS; k++){
    if (fgets(string, sizeof(string), fp) == 0){
        break;
    }
    fscanf(fp,"%d %f %d %d %d %d %d %f %f %f", &stationInfo[k].stationID, &stationInfo[k].temperature, &stationInfo[k].year, &stationInfo[k].month, &stationInfo[k].day, &stationInfo[k].hour, &stationInfo[k].minute, &stationInfo[k].location.latitude, &stationInfo[k].location.longitude, &regionID);
    printf("%d %1.2f %d %d %d %d %d %f %f\n", stationInfo[k].stationID, stationInfo[k].temperature, stationInfo[k].year, stationInfo[k].month, stationInfo[k].day, stationInfo[k].hour, stationInfo[k].minute, stationInfo[k].location.latitude, stationInfo[k].location.longitude);

}
```

So, my program reads my file almost perfectly, but it will not read the first line of my file. Anyone know what might be causing this problem and how I might be able to fix it?

Comment: We might tell you that if you show us your file.

Comment: Because you're calling `fgets()` before you call `fscanf()`, and it reads the first line.

Comment: In fact, since you do that every time through the loop, your program is only calling `fscanf()` on the even lines in the file.

Comment: @Barmar Nice catch. And I wanted to see the actual file. Dummy:)

Comment: @barmar It's probably just reading the tail of each line, and so it looks like the program is only ignoring the first line.

Comment: @paddy It would only do that if the lines are longer than 100 bytes.

Comment: @barmar It would do that if `fscanf` doesn't read the newline character and leaves it in the stream.

Comment: @Barmar -- the fgets calls other than the first will read (just) the trailing newline of the previous already read line.  So only the first line will appear to be skipped

Comment: @ChrisDodd I see what you're saying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are quite intentionally reading and discarding a line here:

```
if (fgets(string, sizeof(string), fp) == 0) {
```

I think you meant to use `sscanf` instead of `fscanf`, so that you use the data returned to you by `fgets`.

```
sscanf(string,"%d %f %d %d %d %d %d %f %f %f", ... );
```

Comment: Ohh awesome :). This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks :D. I also had another question. I'm asked to find the average temperature of the stationInfo.temprature floats. What I originally did was if(stationInfo[k].temperature != 0) t++; and totalTemp+= stationInfo[k].temperature. Then later, divide totalTemp by t. This causes me to have a huge number, and if I look at t, it is also a huge number. What would you say the best option of doing this is?

Comment: My guess is that you didn't initialise `t` or `totalTemp` to zero before the loop.  The other possibility is that your values were not read correctly - you don't check the result of `sscanf`.  But if your output is otherwise correct, then make sure you initialised the values. Another possibility is you're using the wrong format specifier in your `printf` when you output the value.

Comment: I've initialized it and I believe my inputs are good. Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/MkgxgiF1 If you could take a look, that would be much appriciated :)

EDIT: totalTemp works as it should, it's just t that isn't working.

Comment: Are all the floating point values in your struct `float` or `double`?

Comment: Some are ints but the only one I use (temperature) is a float. EDIT: Fixed it, my if statement is poorly formatted and that messed it up :). Thanks.

Comment: Try printing out the value of `t` every time you increment it and see what happens.  There's a chance it's being overwritten somehow, though the only think I can think of is if `scanf` thought it was reading a `double` into `regionID`.

Comment: Okay, glad you sorted it out.  Don't forget to accept this answer if it was helpful =)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your program is "not reading the first line of the file" is because it actually already read the first line when you called

```
if (fgets(string, sizeof(string), fp) == 0)
```

The change to fix this is simple:

```
for(k = 0; k < MAX_STATIONS; k++)
{
    if (fscanf(fp,"%d %f %d %d %d %d %d %f %f %f", &stationInfo[k].stationID,
                                                   &stationInfo[k].temperature,
                                                   &stationInfo[k].year,
                                                   &stationInfo[k].month,
                                                   &stationInfo[k].day,
                                                   &stationInfo[k].hour,
                                                   &stationInfo[k].minute,
                                                   &stationInfo[k].location.latitude,
                                                   &stationInfo[k].location.longitude,
                                                   &regionID) > 10)
    {
        break;
    }
    printf("%d %1.2f %d %d %d %d %d %f %f\n", stationInfo[k].stationID,
                                              stationInfo[k].temperature,
                                              stationInfo[k].year,
                                              stationInfo[k].month,
                                              stationInfo[k].day,
                                              stationInfo[k].hour,
                                              stationInfo[k].minute,
                                              stationInfo[k].location.latitude,
                                              stationInfo[k].location.longitude);
}
```

Note the fscanf's return value:

> On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument list successfully filled. This count can match the expected number of items or be less (even zero) due to a matching failure, a reading error, or the reach of the end-of-file.

Hope this is what you are looking for!

Comment: Great :). This is an awesome solution as well. Thanks

Comment: This is a dangerous way to read data files.  Using a line-based approach is better.  Or at least adding an "ignore to end of line" format to the `fscanf` call.